# how to group in regex matching correctly?

Tags: regex, replace

consider following scenario

```
input string = "WIPR.NS"
```

i have to replace this with "WIPR2.NS"

i am using following logic.

```
match pattern =  "(.*)\.NS$"    \\ any string that ends with .NS

replace pattern = "$12.NS"
```

In above case, since there is no group with index 12, i get result $12.NS

But what i want is "WIPR2.NS".

If i don't have digit 2 to replace, it works in all other cases but not working for 2.

How to resolve this case?

Thanks in advance,
Alok

Comment: pattern = "\.NS$", replacement = "2.NS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually depends entirely on your regex engine (I'm not familiar with those that use `$1` to represent a capture group, I'm more used to `\1` but you'd have the same problem with that).

Some will provide a delimiter that you can use, like:

```
replace pattern = "${1}2.NS"
```

which clearly indicates that you want capture group 1 followed by the literal `2.NS`.

---

In fact, by looking at [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html), it appears that's *exactly* the way to do it (assuming .NET):

> To replace with the first backreference immediately followed by the digit 9, use `${1}9`. If you type `$19`, and there are less than 19 backreferences, the `$19` will be interpreted as literal text, and appear in the result string as such.

---

Also keep in mind that Jay provides an excellent answer for this *specific* use case that doesn't require capture groups at all (by just replacing `.NS` with `2.NS`).

You may want to look into that as a possibility - I'll leave this answer here since:

- it's the accepted answer; and
- it probably better for the more complex cases, like changing `X([A-Z])4([A-Z])` with `X${1}5${2}`, where you have variable text on either side of the bit you wish to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything with what precedes the `.NS`, since only what is being matched is subject to replacement.

`match pattern = "\.NS$"` (any string that ends with .NS -- don't forget to escape the `.`)
`replace pattern = "2.NS"`

You can further refine this with lookaround zero-width assertions, but that depends on your regex engine, and you have not specified the environment/programming language in which you are working.